# Change thumbnail size in Windows Explorer in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

How can I change the thumbnail size of image, video in Windows Explorer in Windows 8?

There's no friendly slider like in windows 7.

Comment: Are you referring to the thumbnails in explorer (desktop version) or in the metro file explorer?

Comment: in explorer, the usual one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Explorer on the desktop, you can increase the size of the thumbnail by clicking on the `view` tab and selecting from the icon size choices listed. these are the same choices available in Windows 7.

In addition, you can enable the preview pane in the same location and see an extremely large version of the currently selected file.

Comment: is there a way to bring back the slider like in windows 7?

Comment: Unknown. But given the neglected state of the desktop side, I doubt one is coming either.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the zoom feature of a mouse scroll wheel to get the same effect. Simply hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and rotate the wheel to "zoom" the display.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers by Graham and Jared, you can also change the thumbnail size for different categories such as documents, picture etc.

E.g. the Pictures folder:

1. Change the thumbnail size
2. Open the folder Properties (right click > Properties) and click on the 'Customise' tab , and make sure that the folder is optimised for Pictures. Tick 'Apply to all sub folders' and press OK
3. Now open File > Change folder and search options. Click on the view tab and where it says 'Folder Views', click 'Apply to Folders'

Now all Pictures-type folders will have the same thumbnail size